# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, while adding getdate() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[IBS_PodiumSummeryCount]
@locid integer=null
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select sum(status_receved) as Receved, sum(status_parked) as Parked,
 sum(status_requested) as Requested,sum(status_requestedinprocess) as Requestinprocess
  from (select case when (status = 0 ) then 1 else 0 end as status_receved,
case when (status = 2) then 1 else 0 end as status_parked, 
case when (status = 3) then 1 else 0 end as status_requested,
case when(status=4) then 1 else 0 end as status_requestedinprocess
from transaction_tbl where locid = @locid   and status in (0,2,3,4))  a;
end
```

but i want to get last 24 hour data from my sql server..i added **getdate() -1** in my where condition. so changed my stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[IBS_PodiumSummeryCount]
@locid integer=null
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select sum(status_receved) as Receved, sum(status_parked) as Parked,
 sum(status_requested) as Requested,sum(status_requestedinprocess) as Requestinprocess
  from (select case when (status = 0 ) then 1 else 0 end as status_receved,
case when (status = 2) then 1 else 0 end as status_parked, 
case when (status = 3) then 1 else 0 end as status_requested,
case when(status=4) then 1 else 0 end as status_requestedinprocess
from transaction_tbl where locid = @locid and getdate()-1  and status in (0,2,3,4))  a;
```

end
but now getting error like this:
*An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.*

Comment: sir i want to get last 24 hours data...so i did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `.. AND datetimetocompare between DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()`

Comment: you need to have a datetime column to compare. Do you have datetime column in `transaction_tbl`?